# Issue with installing android studio - windows 32 bit

Tags: android, android-studio, arm, 32-bit, haxm

I have HP Laptop with the following configuration -

Processor-Intel Core 2 Duo.

Windows - 7 Home Premium - 32-Bit (SP-1).

Ram - 4GB.

No graphics card(actually some inbuilt graphics support of 256MB I am not sure).

I have installed android studio V3.0(for 32-bit) but when I tried to launch the emulator, (even with arm support) it just starts up and crashes after startup.

I get an error like your processor does not support VT-x. ( I have also checked with Microsoft HAM tool, that my processor does not support it, so I need to use system image with ARM support.)

Now my question is whether I can run ARM support emulator on my machine or not, if yes please tell some crisp and easy steps to do so, since I have also tried 2.7" QVGA screen( lowest resolution) And 128MB Ram allocation, it just crashes after startup with error like-> (Your program has stopped working).

Please suggest any workaround and I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

ARM emulator is very resource intensive, even for current machines. I suggest you to use a real device connected to your development machine.

An alternative could be GenyMotion https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio V3.0 doesn't support many features for windows 32 bit System. I recommend you to use Android Studio v2.2.3 instead of 3.0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -1):

U gonna need to enable the VT-X option. Which can be done in the boot menu options. Vt-X is disabled by default in HP laptops.

And HAMx can be downloaded from Intel website. This will help in booting them in the emulator. But with your system configuration, i recommend u stick to eclipse - android.

Comment: Thanks, but Microsoft tool already displayed that it is not included in my version of laptop. So any other workaround ? Android Studio V3.0 will not run on laptops those don't have VT-x support?

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to Install HAMx from Android Studio, it shows the success message that "Your system is capable to run blah blah, in certain mode" but when I allocate RAM and try to install, and finish it fails. Will using older versions for Android studio help or shall I stop trying since its already been 2 days long that I have tried for the same, and nothing positive has turned up.Phew.!!!!

Comment: your system is capable of running but using Intel Core 2 duo will take a hell lot of time to run and build even if you succeed in installing studio. (Source: From my horrible experience with Intel i5 - 4GB - 1GB GPU)

Comment: Actually android studio installation is successful, gradle build is also successful, but while trying to launch Emulator from AVD, it crashes, unable to connect physical device as well (GT-I9082, Samsung), it is connected to my system properly (as PTP/MTP, and I have enabled developer option, a system icon is present under C drive that shows that device is connected to my system) but it does not shows up in the AVD. Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you enable USB debugging in the Developer option (mobile)

Comment: Yes that option is enabled on in mobile. Still It does not show up.

Comment: In SDK ??? DO I need to install it first ???? Some posts on the internet told about Manage option by clicking computer and updating driver I am unclear about it.

Comment: U can find that in the SDK manager! and u can also try searching drivers for your mobile model. That might also help!

Comment: Installed google usb driver still no help...I don't know what the issue it has enabled debugging mode and developer option I can access files of my phone through laptop but still android studio won't detect it

Comment: It's because of the driver issue! Try finding a driver for your device or any kind of connection tools. That might help.